# How to get function to run within if statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to create a new WordPress plugin and have setup an Options page though am having some troubles making my Dropdown menu's selection trigger a function.

This is the function I'm calling in my options page.

I'm attempting to make it so when the value of the Dropdown menu is set to "2" to run the function to hide the Admin Toolbar.

When echoing out $wp_icon it shows either 1 or 2 is being passed.
However when 2 is selected it doesn't ever seem to run the function within the if statement but will call any other code.

```
function my_plugins_options() {


    if (isset($_POST['wp_icon'])) { $wp_icon = $_POST['wp_icon']; update_option('wp_icon', $wp_icon); }
    $wp_icon = get_option('wp_icon');

    include 'page.php';

    if ($wp_icon == 2) {
        function remove_toolbar_nodes($wp_admin_bar) { $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('wp-logo'); }
        add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'remove_toolbar_nodes', 999);
    }   


}
```

page.php

```
<form method="POST">
    <label for="wp_icon">WordPress Icon</label>
    <select id="wp_icon" name="wp_icon">
        <option value="1" <?php selected( $wp_icon, 1 ); ?>>Show</option>
        <option value="2" <?php selected( $wp_icon, 2 ); ?>>Hide</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button button-primary button-large">
</form>
```

The expected result is to have it so when setting the option to "Hide" it would pass the value 2 and then hide the WordPress Icon in the dashboard.

Comment: Your code isn't nearly sufficient to understand what's going on. At least I don't see anything wrong with it (except for the fact that you're declaring a function inside an `if` condition that's inside another function... that feels wrong to me, personal preference I guess).

Answer (score 0):

You created a function but you haven't called it - used.

Check the code below if it is working as expected:

```
<?php

//function definition
function remove_toolbar_nodes($wp_admin_bar) 
{ 
    //just for debugiing - remove line below if success
    echo '<H1>remove_toolbar_nodes executed!</h1>'; 

    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('wp-logo'); 
}

function my_plugins_options() {

    if (isset($_POST['wp_icon'])) { $wp_icon = $_POST['wp_icon']; update_option('wp_icon', $wp_icon); }
    $wp_icon = get_option('wp_icon');

    include 'page.php';

    if ($wp_icon == 2) {
        //function call - requires () after the name of function;
        remove_toolbar_nodes($wp_admin_bar);
        add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'remove_toolbar_nodes', 999);
    }   

}
```

you should see debug printed from the function:

> remove_toolbar_nodes executed!

that you can remove of course :)